# SQL2008 Won't Work After SP1 Install?

Tags: sql-server-2008, service-pack

I have SQL2008 installed on my Win2008 server, and its been working fine - I have sites running using SQL databases etc..

I thought I would install SQL2008 SP1, but after install I cannot connect to SQL via Management Studio, and in configuration manager I cannot start SQL?

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to #MYINSTANCENAME#.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

I'm not really a techie so a bit stuck?? any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look through event viewer on the server and sql server error logs (SSMS can do this under management) to see what happened. Very important to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Well after 3 restarts, I was able to start the service in configuration manager?  Now its fine!?